# How to render html text inside a html body

Tags: html

I have some text like below saved in a text file

```
&lt;b&gt;This is my life&lt;/b&gt;
```

I want to show this text as looking below

> **This is my life**

But currently in my html page i can see just this text

> <b>This is my life</b>

How i can achieve step 1 ..?

I am getting the above text in a html page as follows

```
  <p class="demo"><c:out value="${demo.text}"/></p>
```

it's basically a struts application and jsp pages .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text in saved text file is html special chars encoded. You need to decode it before inserting. For example replace `&lt;` to `<` and `&gt;` to `>` character in all text saved in text file and then insert result into html page.

Comment: It depends on the language or program which you use. Most of your questions is about Java, so I guess you have something written in this language. Please, add more info to your question.